# QueryDSL not finding correct parameter types

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I get an exception when executing a JPAQuery since I updated QueryDsl to version 4.2.1. Before I was on 3.7.4, where it worked fine.

I isolated the problem with this entity:

```
@Entity(name = "TEST")
public class Test implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TEST_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TEST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I wrote a JUnit test which calls this method:

```
public void test() {
    QTest qTest= QTest.test;
    JPAQuery<Test> query = getJpaQueryFactory().selectFrom(qTest);
    query.where(qTest.name.startsWith("test"));
    List<Test> tests = query.fetch();
}
```

This runs fine and returns what it should. However, when I reverse the order on the StringExpression.startsWith method, I get a weird Exception.

```
public void test() {
    QTest qTest= QTest.test;
    JPAQuery<Test> query = getJpaQueryFactory().selectFrom(qTest);
    StringExpression longName = Expressions.asString("test01");
    query.where(longName.startsWith(qTest.name));
    List<Test> tests = query.fetch();
}
```

On the fetch() method, I get:

```
IllegalArgumentException : You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String
for parameter 1 with expected type of class java.lang.Boolean from query string
select test from TEST test where ?1 like concat(test.name,?2) escape '!'.
```

I used the debugger to dig into the querydsl code, and as the Exception states, the query builder expects a boolean for parameter 1, but I have no idea why.

Additionally, it puts '%' as parameter 1, and my search string "test01" as parameter 2. It should be the other way around though.

Has anybody seen this before? To me it seems to be a bug in QueryDSL 4.2.1, but maybe there is an oversight from my side.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you end up solving your problem writing reverse matches? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: No sorry, I never found a solution to this. ¨